# Variable number of fields with MongoDB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, attributes, mongoid, entity-attribute-value

I want to model e-commerce product attributes that can be changed in run-time.

So for example, on the Create Product page, the user adds a certain product with attributes: *color, size*. And then adds some other product with different attributes: *resolution*, *diagonal size*. 
Basically the user is able to define new attributes at run-time.

How do I handle variable attributes in the product model? I'm used to relational databases where the fields of each table are defined a priori.

---

Edit: I'm using Mongoid. Let me be more specific. Let's say I have this product model:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  field :description
  field :price
# attributes not known yet ???
end
```

The other fields of the product are clearly defined in the model, but not the attributes. Perhaps Mongoid/MongoDB doesn't care whether they are defined in the model or not, and just adds them in the document?

Comment: Updated my answer for Mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done for you.  It just works.  Add the attributes and save them.
How it's done depends on what adapter you're using.

[Here's a simple guide to setting it up from MongoDB.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started).
And [this page has documentation you'd need if you're using MongoMapper.](http://mongomapper.com/)

Using [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/)? Again, just set attributes (you'll have to set and access them like a hash: use `[]=` and `[]`), and save it.  [Dynamic fields](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dynamic.html)!